# Is there a way to correctly set "media kind" in Apple Music 1.2.4.3?

Tags: itunes, music, audiobook

I just bit the bullet and updated my Mac OS from 10.14.6 to Monterey 12.4.

Importing my old iTunes library from the xml file worked fine...mostly.

The problem is, I had a ton of TV shows, movies, and audiobooks.  In the old iTunes, they were all correctly tagged with the proper media type.

In the new "Music" app, when I go to "get info" and find the "media type" dropdown, there is exactly one entry that I can select.  It's either "music" or "music video" depending if the selected item is an audio file or a video file.

Needless to say this is a MAJOR regression, and also makes shuffle completely unusable as it will shuffle in all tracks from all audiobooks along with all songs.

How can I fix this?  Is my only option to delete all the audiobooks and non-music videos from my "Music" app library?  Or is there some hack I can use to correctly identify non-music media files while still having everything in the one app like the old iTunes app?

Incidentally I also haven't yet attempted to sync my iPod Touch (last generation) with my computer; I don't know how that will go.  Links or advice welcome on this point.  Not the end of the world if I can't sync TV shows, movies and audiobooks to it anymore, but it will probably push me away from Apple devices for the future.

Comment: Simply updating should have brought the existing structure over, untouched. Why import from XML?

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't know if it should have, but it didn't.  I got the XML idea from https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/430999/151730.  It's worth mentioning I have a full bootable backup of the computer from before the upgrade, so if I need to grab any files from there to get this import to work correctly, I can.  I just want the media types set correctly, but the non-music media types don't seem to be available at all...?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'd have done better importing from the .itl, but it's been so long since i played with these structures, I'm a bit out of touch. The .xml hasn't been the 'master file' for a long time.

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks, I suppose I could try the `.itl`, but is there an implication there that the modern Music app *does* have a way to mark media files as audiobook or TV show or movie, but that it can't be accessed except through importing from a library file created with a deprecated iTunes version?  If the feature is there shouldn't it be accessible from the current app?  If not that seems kind of ridiculous.

Comment: Apple have been reducing functionality of some old stalwarts for many years now - but hey, look, new shiny. I only have one Mac here capable of running anything newer than Mojave. The new M1 was a straight migrate, but has nothing but 'music' on it, so there's nothing I can really test.

Comment: Did you try upgrading to Catalina first because that was when Music (app) is first introduced and thus may focus more on a smooth and reliable upgrade (from iTunes)?

Comment: @JoyJin I didn't.  Might have if I had known that, though, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Audiobooks are now supported in the Books app. Music, as you'd guess by the name, just does music.

iTunes used to try and do everything (poorly IMHO), and Apple eventually listened to the various opinions re. bloat, and split the various functions into separate apps, hence Music, Books, Podcasts. This allows a proper UI for each media type.

Separate your Audiobooks from your Music library and import them to Books. They can then be synced to an iOS device by enabling sync in the Finder panels that appear for your device when it's plugged in.

If you have purchases from Audible, they are supported in the macOS Books app by authorising your computer on the Audible website. That authorisation carries over to Books on your iOS device also, but there's also the Audible app on iOS which may offer a better experience. See:

https://help.audible.com/s/article/how-to-listen-to-audible-audiobooks-with-the-apple-books-app?language=en_US

Note. If you use iCloud you'll find that while EPUBs and PDFs added to Books will automatically sync (when enabled) to your iOS device via iCloud, it appears Audiobooks do not, and thus have to be synced via Finder.